# Trying to ignore flake8 W503 error in Sublime, but edits to user settings do not affect it

Tags: sublimetext3, flake8

I have tried editing my user Sublime Linter settings to:

```
"linters":
    {
        "flake8": {
            "args": ["--ignore W503"],
        },

    }
```

However, this has not gotten rid of the error flags.

Answer (score 1):

First you probably want `--extend-ignore` and not `--ignore`

second, your arguments are malformed, you're telling flake8 to ignore the `W503` code (note the space at the beginning)

Here's how you could configure sublime to do what you want:

```
I have tried editing my user Sublime Linter settings to:

"linters":
    {
        "flake8": {
            "args": ["--extend-ignore", "W503"],
        },

    }
```

though I'd suggest instead to configure flake8 via its config file:

```
[flake8]
extend-ignore = W503
```

note that you shouldn't need that, since W503 is part of the default ignore set

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer

Comment: Thank you for the correction!  For some reason, it is still flagging the W503 error.  I tried editing the sublime preferences, as well as creating a flake8 config file in my home directory.  Any thoughts on what could be going wrong? I am operating on a Mac.

Comment: Also, I'm noticing after temporarily removing the flake8 linter from my packages, the error is STILL flagged.  Could it be a different package in play?